How to make transparent JavaFX stage transparent for mouse events for Linux X11?
I have a transparent stage and I need when user click inside this stage then mouse event to be passed to a window that is behind my JavaFX stage (for example, if there is a text editor behind my stage then mouse event should be passed to that editor window). By other words I need the Stage to be transparent for mouse events.
This is my code:
public class Test12 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-color: black");
        vBox.setMouseTransparent(true);
        var scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 300);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("test.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

CSS
.root { -fx-background-color: transparent; }

Could anyone say how to do it, if it is possible.
UPDATE
This is a C program that makes the right half of the window transparent for mouse events (use gcc -o program program.c -lX11 -lXext):
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/extensions/shape.h>

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#define _NET_WM_STATE_REMOVE        0    // remove/unset property
#define _NET_WM_STATE_ADD           1    // add/set property
#define _NET_WM_STATE_TOGGLE        2    // toggle property

Bool makeAlwaysOnTop(Display* display,  Window mywin) {
    int screen = DefaultScreen(display);
    Window root = RootWindow(display, screen);
    Atom wmStateAbove = XInternAtom( display, "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE", 1 );
    if( wmStateAbove != None ) {
        printf( "_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE has atom of %ld\n", (long)wmStateAbove );
    } else {
        printf( "ERROR: cannot find atom for _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE !\n" );
        return False;
    }

    Atom wmNetWmState = XInternAtom( display, "_NET_WM_STATE", 1 );
    if( wmNetWmState != None ) {
        printf( "_NET_WM_STATE has atom of %ld\n", (long)wmNetWmState );
    } else {
        printf( "ERROR: cannot find atom for _NET_WM_STATE !\n" );
        return False;
    }

    if( wmStateAbove != None )
    {
        XClientMessageEvent xclient;
        memset( &xclient, 0, sizeof (xclient) );
        xclient.type = ClientMessage;
        xclient.window = mywin;
        xclient.message_type = wmNetWmState;
        xclient.format = 32;
        xclient.data.l[0] = _NET_WM_STATE_ADD;
        xclient.data.l[1] = wmStateAbove;
        xclient.data.l[2] = 0;
        xclient.data.l[3] = 0;
        xclient.data.l[4] = 0;
        XSendEvent( display,
          root,
          False,
          SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask,
          (XEvent *)&xclient );
        XFlush(display);
        return True;
    }
    return False;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

void makeHalfTransparent(Display* dpy,  Window win) {
    Pixmap shape = XCreatePixmap(dpy, win, 400, 300, 1);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(dpy, shape, 0, NULL);
    XSetFillStyle(dpy, gc, FillSolid);
    XSetForeground(dpy, gc, 0);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, shape, gc, 0, 0, 400, 300);
    XSetForeground(dpy, gc, 1);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, shape, gc, 0, 0, 200, 300);
    XShapeCombineMask(dpy, win, ShapeBounding, 0, 0, shape, ShapeSet);
    XFreeGC(dpy, gc);
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

int main() {
    Display *dpy;
    Window win;

    XEvent event;
    int screen;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (dpy == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        return 1;
    }

    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, RootWindow(dpy, screen), 10, 10, 400, 300, 1, BlackPixel(dpy, screen), WhitePixel(dpy, screen));
    XSelectInput(dpy, win, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);

    XMapWindow(dpy, win);
    makeAlwaysOnTop(dpy, win);
    makeHalfTransparent(dpy, win);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &event);
        if (event.type == KeyPress) {
            break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, win);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}

This is my JavaFX application that using JNA must make the right half of the window transparent for mouse events (by other words I ported makeHalfTransparent function from C to Java):
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.unix.X11;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class JavaFxTest10 extends Application {

    public static interface CustomX11 extends Library {

        CustomX11 INSTANCE = (CustomX11) Native.load("X11", CustomX11.class);

        X11.Display XOpenDisplay(String display_name);

        int XFreeGC(X11.Display display, X11.GC gc);

        void XSetForeground(X11.Display display, X11.GC gc, int foreground);

        X11.Pixmap XCreatePixmap(X11.Display display, X11.Window w, int width, int height, int depth);

        void XFillRectangle(X11.Display display, X11.Pixmap drawable, X11.GC gc, int x, int y, int width, int height);

        X11.GC XCreateGC(X11.Display display, X11.Pixmap drawable, int valuemask, X11.XGCValues values);

        void XFreePixmap(X11.Display display, X11.Pixmap pixmap);

        int XFetchName(X11.Display display, Window w, PointerByReference windowName);

        X11.Window XDefaultRootWindow(X11.Display display);

        X11.Window XCreateSimpleWindow(X11.Display display, X11.Window rootWindow, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int h, int g);

        X11.Atom XInternAtom(X11.Display display, String atom_name, boolean only_if_exists);

        void XChangeProperty(X11.Display display, X11.Window window, X11.Atom property, X11.Atom type, int format, int mode, Pointer data, int nelements);

        void XSetFillStyle(X11.Display display, X11.GC gc, int fillStyle);

        void XFillRectangle(X11.Display display, X11.Drawable drawable, X11.GC gc, int x, int y, int width, int height);
    }

    public interface Xext extends Library {

       Xext INSTANCE = Native.load("Xext", Xext.class);

       void XShapeCombineMask(X11.Display display, X11.Window w, int shapeOp, int x, int y, X11.Pixmap shape, int shapeKind);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var button = new Button("Push Me");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            var p = getWIndowPoiter(primaryStage);
            var window = getWindow(p);
            printWindowTitle(window);//checking pointer
            makeHalfTransparent(window, (int) primaryStage.getWidth(), (int) primaryStage.getHeight());
        });
        var hBox = new HBox(button);
        hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        var content = new VBox();
        content.setMouseTransparent(true);
        VBox.setVgrow(content, Priority.ALWAYS);

        var mainBox = new VBox(hBox, content);
        mainBox.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-color: black");
        var scene = new Scene(mainBox, 400, 300);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("test.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JafaFX Window 777");
    }

    private Pointer getWIndowPoiter(Stage stage) {
        try {
            final Method getPeer = Window.class.getDeclaredMethod("getPeer", null);
            getPeer.setAccessible(true);
            final Object tkStage = getPeer.invoke(stage);
            final Method getRawHandle = tkStage.getClass().getMethod("getRawHandle");
            getRawHandle.setAccessible(true);
            var l = (Long) getRawHandle.invoke(tkStage);
            final Pointer pointer = new Pointer(l);
            System.out.println(pointer);
            return pointer;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private X11.Window getWindow( Pointer windowPointer) {
        X11.Window window = new X11.Window(Pointer.nativeValue(windowPointer));
        return window;
    }

    private void printWindowTitle(X11.Window window) {
        final X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
        X11.Display display = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);
        PointerByReference windowNameReference = new PointerByReference();
        int status = X11.INSTANCE.XFetchName(display, window, windowNameReference);

        if (status == 1) {
            Pointer windowNamePointer = windowNameReference.getValue();
            String windowTitle = windowNamePointer.getString(0);
            System.out.println("Window Title: " + windowTitle);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to fetch window name.");
        }
    }

    public static final int FillSolid = 0;
    public static final int ShapeBounding = 0;
    public static final int ShapeSet = 0;

    private void makeHalfTransparent(X11.Window win, int width, int height) {
        X11.Display display = CustomX11.INSTANCE.XOpenDisplay(null);
        //Pixmap shape = XCreatePixmap(dpy, win, 400, 300, 1);
        X11.Pixmap shape = CustomX11.INSTANCE.XCreatePixmap(display, win, width, height, 1);
        //GC gc = XCreateGC(dpy, shape, 0, NULL);
        X11.GC gc2 = CustomX11.INSTANCE.XCreateGC(display, shape, 0, null);
        //XSetFillStyle(dpy, gc, FillSolid);
        CustomX11.INSTANCE.XSetFillStyle(display, gc2, FillSolid);
        //XSetForeground(dpy, gc, 0);
        CustomX11.INSTANCE.XSetForeground(display, gc2, 0);
        //XFillRectangle(dpy, shape, gc, 0, 0, 400, 300);
        CustomX11.INSTANCE.XFillRectangle(display, shape, gc2, 0, 0, width, height);
        //XSetForeground(dpy, gc, 1);
        CustomX11.INSTANCE.XSetForeground(display, gc2, 1);
        //XFillRectangle(dpy, shape, gc, 0, 0, 200, 300);
        CustomX11.INSTANCE.XFillRectangle(display, shape, gc2, 0, 0, width / 2, height);
        //XShapeCombineMask(dpy, win, ShapeBounding, 0, 0, shape, ShapeSet);
        Xext.INSTANCE.XShapeCombineMask(display, win, ShapeBounding, 0, 0, shape, ShapeSet);
        //XFreeGC(dpy, gc);
        CustomX11.INSTANCE.XFreeGC(display, gc2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

But it doesn't work in JavaFX. Could anyone help me to make JavaFX window transparent for mouse events for Linux X11?

if there is a text editor behind my stage You mean another application which is not a JavaFX application, correct?

@Abra Yes, that's correct.

I can't reproduce your problem. I run your code and I see a black rectangle on the screen. Behind the rectangle is Google Chrome showing your question on SO. I double click on a word in your question - that is inside the black rectangle - and the word is highlighted. Refer to this screen capture. Are you saying that doesn't happen for you? I am using OpenJFX 21.0.5 and Eclipse 2024-09 (that contains JDK 21) on Lenovo laptop running Windows 10.

@Abra Thank you very much for this wonderful information :). At least I won't solve this problem for windows :). But in Ubuntu it doesn't work. Do you have VM to test it with Ubuntu?

On my Mac, it does the same as described in the OP; i.e. mouse events do not pass through to the window behind the transparent window.

See also Mac: MouseEvents don't go through transparent stage, which offers some historical perspective.

Platform.isSupported (ConditionalFeature.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW) returns true on MacOS, but I cannot reproduce the result of @Abra.

@trashgod It is possible co create a transparent window in Ubuntu too. The problem is to make this transparent window to be transparent for mouse events. Currently it is possible only in Windows - see my code before UPDATE section.

The ConditionalFeature API mentions "XComposite extension" on Linux systems, but I have no knowledge of it.

Related (unanswered): How to focus on applications behind the JavaFX window when clicking on transparent areas?

You can try XShapeCombineMask with JNA to make the javafx window transparent for mouse events. Right now, your makeHalfTransparent function looks fine, but you're likely not applying the mask correctly to the javafx window.
getWindowPointer needs fetched and applied the shape mask XSHapeCombineMask matching dimensions of the stage and call XFlush after applying the mask

That's funny. Several days I tried to solve this problem. Уou are right. I didn't call  XFlush after applying the mask.

Glad to help , good luck!

Not sure if this kind of workaround would be acceptable for your use case but you can achieve this effect with minimizing the window for a moment, using java fx Robot to clik the mouse and maximizing the window back. This can be done with event handler like this:
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        primaryStage.setIconified(true);
        robot.mousePress(MouseButton.PRIMARY);
        robot.mouseRelease(MouseButton.PRIMARY);
        primaryStage.setIconified(false);
    });

